# How to hide SearchBar on scroll in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to hide Search bar in my app like Apple did in their messages app:

[image]

I've already implemented UISearchBar in SwiftUI:

```
struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {
@Binding var text: String

class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @Binding var text: String

    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        _text = text
    }

    func searchBar(_: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        text = searchText
    }
}

func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(text: $text)
}

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
    let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
    searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchBar.placeholder = "Поиск по названию, дедлайну или описанию"
    return searchBar
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context _: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
    uiView.text = text
}
}
```

How can I implement hide and hiding animation in SwiftUI?

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: It can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59710150/adding-a-search-bar-to-navigationview-in-swiftui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **SwiftUI 3.0 (iOS 15.0+)**

Apple made it possible in very native way.

You just need to use `.searchable()` modifier with view you want to make *searchable* and ensure that you have `NavigationView` as parent of your views.

**Example**

```swift
struct CountriesView: View {
    let countries = ["United States", "India", "Ukraine", "Russia", "Sweden"]
    @State var search: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(countries.filter({
                // we filter our country list by checking whether country name
                // does contain search string or not
                $0.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased()) 
           })) { country in
                Text(country)
            }.searchable(text: $search)
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, you can use **computed properties** to filter your array in more convenient way.

Then, the computed property for the filter from the example will be:

```swift
var searchResults: [String] {
   return countries.filter({$0.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased())})
}
```

So, `List` will look like this:

```swift
List(searchResults) {
    // ...
}
```

p.s. you can learn more about computed variables & properties in [this swift.org article](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID358)